# Append 2 Mysql rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two step registration, one with vital data, like email username and password, and a second optional one with personal info, like bio, eye color, etc.. i have 2 exec files for these, the first ofc writes the data in the first part of the database, leaving like 30 columns of personal data blank. The second one does another row, but with the vital data empty now.. I would like to append, or join these two rows, so all the info is in one row..

Here is the 2nd one

```
 $qry = "UPDATE `performers` SET `Bemutatkozas` = '$bemuatkozas', `Feldob` = '$feldob', `Lehangol` = '$lehangol', `Szorzet` = '$szorzet', `Jatekszerek` = '$jatek', `Kukkolas` = '$kukkolas', `Flort` ='$flort', `Szeretek` = '$szeretek', `Utalok` = '$utalok', `Fantaziak` = '$fantaziak', `Titkosvagyak` = '$titkos_vagyak, `Suly` = '$suly', `Magassag` = '$magassag', `Szemszin` = '$szemszin', `Hajszin` = '$hajszin', `Hajhossz` = '$hajhossz', `Mellboseg` ='$mellboseg', `Orarend` = '$orarend', `Beallitottsag` = '$szexualis_beallitottsag', `Pozicio` = '$pozicio', `Dohanyzas` = '$cigi', `Testekszer` = '$pc', `Tetovalas` ='$tetko', `Szilikon` ='$szilikon', `Fetish1` = '$pisiszex', `Fetish2` = '$kakiszex', `Fetish3` = '$domina', `Testekszerhely` = '$pchely', `Tetovalashely` = '$tetkohely', `Csillagjegy` = '$csillagjegy', `Parral` = '$par', `Virag` = '$virag' WHERE `Username` ='" .  $_POST['username']. "'";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);


//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("location: perf_register_success.php");
    exit();
```

I'm not sure if $_POST works here. I have the form, then the exec of that form, which works, then this form, and this is the exec of that.. Anyway I always get "query failed" message, which is in the else statement of the 'if' i'm using. What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as `WHERE` with an insert http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: We should keep a score board of questions with vulnerable sql injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax for UPDATE is as follows:

```
UPDATE table SET columnA=valueA, columnB=valueB WHERE condition=value
```

([documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html))

Thus, your query should look like the following:

```
$qry = "UPDATE performers SET Bemutatkozas = $bemuatkozas, Feldob = $feldob, Lehangol = $lehangol [...] WHERE Username ='" .  $_POST['username']. "'
```

You'll have to replace [...] with all your values (that's gonna take some time) but hopefully you get the pattern.

Other than that there are a number of things you should improve/change in your code but I'll just point you to [jeroen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11462668/1329367) in this question since he pretty much covers it all.

Comment: Thank you mister, worked like a charm. I definately will improve security over time, I just want to get past the basics, then cover that :)

Answer (score 1):

You want [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) instead of `INSERT` for your second query.

Apart from that you really need to fix that sql injection error, preferably by switching to PDO or mysqli in combination with prepared statements. The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

And whatever solution you take, you need to add proper error handling, suppressing errors is wrong, especially when you try to fix a problem but even in a production site, errors need to be logged, not ignored.

Comment: @trisztann Maybe you can update your question with what you have tried?